# Magento 2 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName() on null in

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1

How solve this issue? Error log (PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName() on null in) is for line 4: $page_title = $brand->getName();

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $brand = $this->getCurrentBrand();
    $page_title = $brand->getName();
    $meta_description = $brand->getMetaDescription();
    $meta_keywords = $brand->getMetaKeywords();
    $this->_addBreadcrumbs();
    if($page_title){
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($page_title);   
    }
    if($meta_keywords){
        $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($meta_keywords);   
    }
    if($meta_description){
        $this->pageConfig->setDescription($meta_description);   
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->getCurrentBrand()` is returning NULL.

You can solve the issue by ensuring the data is set before the layout is prepared.

Answer (score 0):

You can add code on your theme `Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer` File.

Previous Code

```
$brandBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Rokanthemes\Brand\Block\Brand\View');
$_brand = $brandBlock->getCurrentBrand();
```

Updated Code

```
if($this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'brand' && $this->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'rokanthemesbrand') {

$brandBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Rokanthemes\Brand\Block\Brand\View');

$_brand = $brandBlock->getCurrentBrand();
}
```